# GET and POST with Flask - optimum performance

Tags: python, flask, redis

I have this code to POST and save a digest to redis, and retrieve it from redis on a GET. This uses Python and Flask, of course.

```
@app.route("/message/<shasum>", methods=['GET'])
def get_message(shasum):
    message = redis.get(shasum)
    if message:
        return jsonify(message=message)
    else:
        abort(404)

@app.route("/digest", methods=['POST'])
def get_digest():
    if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
        message = json.loads(request.data)
        sha = sha256(message['message'].encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        redis.set(sha, message['message'])
        return (jsonify(digest=sha), 201)
    else:
        return (jsonify(message="Bad Request"), 400 )
```

what else can I do to improve the performance of this little piece of code, specifically on the POST side and can it be improved on the GET side too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can avoid the Content-Type check by using [`request.get_json()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.get_json) method.

```
from werkzeug.wrappers import BaseRequest
...

try:
    data = request.get_json()
except BadRequest:
    return (jsonify(message="Bad Request"), 400)

message = data['message']
digest = sha256(message.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
redis.set(sha, message)
return (jsonify(digest=digest), 201)
```

- Use better variable names, `message` can be replaced with `data` and `message` variable can be used to store the actual message from data. Similarly `sha` can be replaced with `digest`.
- The `else` blocks in both functions can be removed as the corresponding `if` blocks are already returning. I personally find lesser indented code much easier to read and it also helps in keeping the [Cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) low.
- There are no check against the data being passed by the user, for example message can be passed as an empty string, `None`, integer etc. You probably want to use some sort of validation here.

Comment: thanks. I was looking to optimize on the redis side. cause right now, irrespective of whether the digest exists in redis, I always write to redis. that seems kinda expensive. thoughts around that?

Comment: @adeledazim Setting and getting the key in Redis is an O(1) operation. You probably want to profile your function to see which part is the slowest.